# Calling a python script inside other python script using two different envs

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have two different Django applications, both are running in the same Linux server (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS), using Python 3.6 64bit.

The **app A** is running in Django 1.11 and a **virtualenv A**.

The **app B** is running in Django 2.1 and a **virtualenv B**.

In the **App B** I need to call a function to migrate tables in **App A**, when I run the command in shell everything works fine.

```
/path/to/envA/python /path/to/appA/manage.py migrate
```

But when I try to run the same command **inside App B** using **subprocess** I have a **no module** error, I suspect this is because of different envs.

This is my code inside App B:

```
subprocess.Popen(["/path/to/envA/python", "/path/to/appA/manage.py", "migrate"], 
                 stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I yet tried to use `shell=True` but this do not work and freeze my console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by passing the `env` variable in `Popen` function:

```
subprocess.Popen(["/path/to/envA/python", "/path/to/appA/manage.py", "migrate"], 
                 stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                 env={"PATH": "/path/to/envA/python"})
```